# stored procedure not working properly error converting datatype

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to get Username by UserId - I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_UsernameByUserId_SP](
        @UserId             int,
        @ExecutionResult    nvarchar(64)    OUTPUT
        )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ExecutionResult = (SELECT TOP 1 Username FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = @Userid);

END
```

Executed by the following method:

```
    public string CallSpRetStr(String spName, SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
    {
        string sRet = null;

        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        myCommand.CommandText = spName;

        myCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionResult", DbType.String);
        myCommand.Parameters[myCommand.Parameters.Count - 1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                OpenConnection();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                CloseConnection();
            }
            sRet = myCommand.Parameters["@ExecutionResult"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }

        return sRet;
    }
```

Called by the following method:

```
    public string GetUsernameByUserId(int UserId)
    {
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserId", UserId);

        return dal.CallSpRetStr("GET_UsernameByUserId_SP", parameters);
    }
```

At runtime I get the following error message (caught by the try-catch in CallSpRetStr): 
'Error converting datatype nvarchar to int'.

I've been banging my head in the wall for more than hour now, trying crazy things etc. 
I have two questions:
1. Does anyone understand what is the problem in all the above?
2. Is anyone aware of a better way to get the username by the userid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the `UserId` column in the `UserProfile` table has a numeric type?

Comment: It seems like a datatype mismatch as your code logic seems fine to me. As @Andomar said, cross check the datatypes of the column and the one which you have specified in the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionResult", DbType.String);
```

should be

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionResult", new string(' ', 64);
```

The [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method expects, for its second parameter, the current value for the named parameter but you pass an enum (`DbType.String == (int)16`). `AddWithValue` then tries to build a parameter with the datatype corresponding to the value passed and thus creates an integer parameter. Of course this is not acceptable by your stored procedure that expects a nvarchar type

Also I would remove any possible misunderstanding on which parameter is the output one using the return value from the AddWithValue instead of an indexing on the parameter collection

```
 SqlParameter p myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionResult", new string(' ', 64);
 p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Notice that we need to create a string of the correct size because AddWithValue doesn't know the expected size of the parameter from the stored procedure and so it creates the parameter with the size equals to the length of the string passed.

Comment: +1 SQL Server is complaining about a conversion from string to numeric, not the other way around.  The error might be triggered when converting the `Username` back to the interger parameter.

Comment: That was it, of course. I wouldn't find it myself in million years. Now it works, but I am still facing a problem because the returned value is just the first letter of the full string (just the first letter of the username). Can you figure out why?

Comment: My fault. Passing a string empty probably creates a parameter with size = 1, try with `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionResult", new string(' ', 64);
);`

Comment: Your help is invaluable. That is working of course. Thanks a lot. I have changed the signature of the sql calling method to this: `public string CallSpRetStr(String spName, SqlParameter[] sqlParams, int ReturnedStringSize)`. And defining the sql parameter like this: `SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@ExecutionResult", SqlDbType.NVarChar, ReturnedStringSize)`; I am wondering... is there any way to have this parameter automatically get size of the returned field from the table? Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters(v=vs.110).aspx), but read carefully why it is not a good idea

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks a million.